# How can I test a dispatch to a redux store in an ES6 class method with Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs, es6-class

I try to test that a dispatch to a redux store is happening inside an ES6 class method, but I'm failing miserably.

Somehow I'm unable to find out how to mock the store to get a response.

The method is quite simple:

```
class Foo {
  …
  bar() {
    store.dispatch({ type: FOO_BAR_BAZ });
  }
  …
};
```

I just want to test that the dispatch happened.

I tried a couple of things, including `redux-mock-store`, but I get no feedback from the store.

```
it('should foo bar baz', () => {
  const store = {
    dispatch: jest.fn(),
  };

  const foobar = new Foo();
  foobar.bar();

  console.log(store.dispatch.mock);
  //=> { calls: [], instances: [], invocationCallOrder: [], results: [] }
});
```

I would be deeply grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jest `store` mock isn't invoked because the class doesn't have access to it. One way around this would be passing in the store to the constructor:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(store) {
    this.store = store
  }

  bar() {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: FOO_BAR_BAZ });
  }
}
```

-

```
it('should foo bar baz', () => {
  const store = {
    dispatch: jest.fn(),
  };

  const foobar = new Foo(store);
  foobar.bar();

  console.log(store.dispatch.mock);
});
```